# What is the reason for different TYPE command behavior in FOR loop?

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, types

I have the following file generated from **robocopy**:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

   ROBOCOPY     ::     Robust File Copy for Windows                              

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

 Started : Sat Dec 09 20:40:18 2017

  Source : D:\shareME\test\
     Dest : \\remoteServer\delME\

    Files : test.zip

  Options : /TEE /COPY:DAT /Z /IS /R:1000000 /W:30 

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                       1    D:\shareME\test\
        Newer            181.8 m    test.zip
 56.0%
 56.1%
 56.1%
 56.1%
 56.2%
 56.2%
 56.2%
 56.3%
 56.3%
 56.3%
 56.4%
 56.4%
 56.4%
 56.5%
 56.5%
 56.5%
 .
 .
 .
 *up to
 68.3%
```

When I use the **type** command on this log file, I get the following (fully desirable as the unnecessary older % are not displayed):

```
 -------------------------------------------------------------------------------

 ROBOCOPY     ::     Robust File Copy for Windows

 -------------------------------------------------------------------------------

   Started : Sat Dec 09 20:40:18 2017

    Source : D:\shareME\test\
      Dest : \\remoteServer\delME\

     Files : test.zip

   Options : /TEE /COPY:DAT /Z /IS /R:1000000 /W:30

 ------------------------------------------------------------------------------

                            1    D:\shareME\test\
  68.6%      Newer                181.8 m        test.zip
```

However, if I put this same command in **for** loop inside a batch file it displays the older % of file copy progress.

```
for /f "tokens=1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23 delims= " %%a in ('type upload2.log') do ( echo %%a %%b %%c .... %%z )
```

as seen here

```
 -------------------------------------------------------------------------------

 ROBOCOPY     ::     Robust File Copy for Windows

 -------------------------------------------------------------------------------

   Started : Sat Dec 09 20:40:18 2017

  Source : D:\shareME\test\
     Dest : \\remoteServer\delME\

    Files : test.zip

   Options : /TEE /COPY:DAT /Z /IS /R:1000000 /W:30

 ------------------------------------------------------------------------------

                            1    D:\shareME\test\
  56.3%      Newer                181.8 m        test.zip
```

What is the reason for this?

It's mandatory that I use the **type** command as the file is in use as long as I need to read it.

Comment: edited. Update: It has appeared to me the problem is that for loop can't handle the large number of tokens generated in the log file. We need the last token in the log file to get how much % copying has completed. This is a common problem for any cmd which generates realtime progress in a log file. How do we tackle getting the last token in the file in these cases out of the thousands of tokens which will rsult if we try to delimit the file for getting the last value

Comment: I haven't checked it fully yet and need to understand it fuly a bit short of time. I'll reply as soon as I understand and try it

Answer (score 1):

The commented batch file code below modifies `upload2.log` from

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

 Started : Sat Dec 09 20:40:18 2017

  Source : D:\shareME\test\
     Dest : \\remoteServer\delME\

    Files : test.zip

  Options : /TEE /COPY:DAT /Z /IS /R:1000000 /W:30 

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                       1    D:\shareME\test\
        Newer            181.8 m    test.zip
 56.0%
 56.1%
 56.1%
 56.1%
 56.2%
 56.2%
 56.2%
 56.3%
 56.3%
 56.3%
 56.4%
 56.4%
 56.4%
 56.5%
 56.5%
 56.5%
 68.3%
```

to

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

 Started : Sat Dec 09 20:40:18 2017

  Source : D:\shareME\test\
     Dest : \\remoteServer\delME\

    Files : test.zip

  Options : /TEE /COPY:DAT /Z /IS /R:1000000 /W:30 

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                       1    D:\shareME\test\
        Newer            181.8 m    test.zip
  68.3%
```

I hope this is the output you expect.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem Define name of log file.
set "LogFile=upload2.log"

rem Does this file exist at all?
if not exist "%LogFile%" goto :EOF

rem Define name of a temporary file created with name of batch
rem file with file extension TMP in folder for temporary files.
set "TmpFile=%TEMP%\%~n0.tmp"

rem Search in log file for lines starting with 0 or more leading spaces,
rem having next at least one digit, followed by 0 or more digits or a point
rem (floating point number), then a percent sign, and 0 or more trailing
rem spaces at end of line using a regular expression. But wanted for output
rem are only those lines NOT matching this expression (inVerted output).
rem The output lines not matching the expression are redirected into the
rem temporary file which is created new or overwritten if existing already.

%SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /V /R /C:"^ *[01234567689][0123456789.]*%% *" "%LogFile%" >"%TmpFile%"

rem Then run again the regular expression search, but this time in a command
rem process in background started by command FOR and with printing to handle
rem STDOUT the lines matching the regular expression captured by FOR.
rem Each captured line is assigned to loop variable I being next assigned
rem to environment variable LastPercentLine. Just the last line found in
rem the log file is of interest for further processing of this batch file.

set "LastPercentLine="
for /F "delims=" %%I in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /R /C:"^ *[01234567689][0123456789.]*%% *" "%LogFile%" 2^>nul') do set "LastPercentLine=%%I"

rem If a line with a percent value could be found at all in the log file,
rem append this line to the temporary file and replace the log file with
rem the temporary file with just the last percent value line. Otherwise
rem delete the temporary file and keep the log file unmodified.

if defined LastPercentLine (
    echo %LastPercentLine%>>"%TmpFile%"
    move /Y "%TmpFile%" "%LogFile%"
) else del "%TmpFile%"

endlocal
```

Redirecting output of a command or console application written to handle **STDOUT** to a file results in getting written to file everything output to **STDOUT** even when the command or application uses special code to move text cursor in console window after output of a line back to beginning of this line to overwrite in console window the just output text with another text.

The output with the percent indication is finally readable in console window as expected because of the special text cursor moving code used by the command/application. But the output redirected into a file contains all output text as the special code to move text cursor to a specific position in console window has no effect on the file.

To get from log file `upload2.log` just the percent value without leading and trailing spaces the batch file can be reduced for example to:

```
@echo off
set "LastPercentValue=0%%"
for /F %%I in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /R /C:"^ *[01234567689][0123456789.]*%% *" "upload2.log" 2^>nul') do set "LastPercentValue=%%I"
echo %LastPercentValue% copied.
set "LastPercentValue="
```

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `del /?`
- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `findstr /?`
- `for /?`
- `goto /?`
- `if /?`
- `move /?`
- `rem /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`